# Прыгает меню при наведении (hover) на пункты

Tags: html, css, меню, hover

Помогите решить проблему. Меню прыгает при наведении. То есть сдвигается влево и вправо.. Нужно чтобы просто фон был при наведении и все..
Сетка bootstrap

```css
body {
 font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#first {
 background: url(../img/header.png) no-repeat center top /cover;
 height: 100vh;
}
header {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 height: 77px;
}
.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100vh;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgba(79,134,157,1);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79,134,157,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(79,134,157,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79,134,157,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79,134,157,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79,134,157,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(79,134,157,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4f869d', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=1 );
}
ul, li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
}
.main_menu_list_item a {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.main_menu_list_item {
 margin: 25px 23px 0 23px;
}
.main_menu_list_item a:hover {
 padding: 10px;
 background: #375f73;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="first">
  <header id="header">
    <nav id="navbar">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="nav_logo">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Логотип">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <ul class="main_menu_list d-flex justify-content-center">
            <li class="main_menu_list_item">
              <a href="#">Главная</a>     
            </li>
            <li class="main_menu_list_item">
              <a href="#">О компании</a> 
            </li>
            <li class="main_menu_list_item">
              <a href="#">Недвижимость и переезд</a> 
            </li>
            <li class="main_menu_list_item">
              <a href="#">Контакты</a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="phone">
            +7 (495) 12-321-345<br>
            +7 (495) 12-321-345
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</section>
```

Comment: какой меню прыгает ?уточните у меня ничего не прыгает

Comment: Влево и вправо пункты смещаются при наведении. Мне нужно чтобы был фон при наведении на меню и бордер с радиусом в 5 пикселей

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При `:hover` вы элементу добавляете `padding` из за этого он смещается ("прыгает"), установите нужный `padding` для элемента по дефолту и при `:hover` меняйте только фон. + для этого элемента(ссылки) лучше добавить еще свойство `display: inline-block/block/flex`